# Directory of BOINC data

Tags: boinc

I can't find where is my data of BOINC. As stated in [this post](http://setiathome.berkeley.edu/forum_thread.php?id=58968&postid=974516#974516) **written 5 years ago**:

> The paths for the BOINC directory and BOINC Data directory are stored in the registry, at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Space Sciences Laboratory, U.C. Berkeley\BOINC Setup

[image: image description]

So I go to that directory. However, the whole folder only 18.2 MB:

[image: image description]

However, when I open the disk usage in BOINC Manager, it says that it has used 553.15 MB:

[image: image description]

So where is the rest?

Comment: Files are marked as system and/or hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Properties screenshot you have posted is for the Program **Files** directory. The data stored by BOINC is stored in the Program**Data** directory (as evidenced by the DATADIR registry key).

Comment: How stupid me. I didn't read the image enough carefully.